# MomentJs monday by week number bug

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a function that grabs the date key with format of YYYY-MM-DD, eg. 2021-03-29 (monday)
get its week number (13), and using that, get that week number's monday, in case of 2021-03-29 it would be the same day, incase of 2021-03-30 it should be 2021-03-29 etc, as long as it's on the same week (by week number)

I have created a sandbox for it.

http://jsfiddle.net/x6sL8k7e/1/

Test code

```
const dateKey = "2021-03-29"
const weekNumber = moment(dateKey, 'YYYY-MM-DD').isoWeek() // getting week nr - 13
    
      
const date = moment(dateKey, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
        .clone()
        .week(weekNumber) // want to get monday for week #13
        .day('Monday')
        
console.log('date', date.format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
```

PS. It works flawlessly with this year's dates (any date)

Comment: Seems like the problem arises near the beginning of the new year. Try the following dates and  see the results go haywire:
```2021-01-01, 
2021-01-04, 
2021-01-11
```

Output:
```"date", "2021-12-27", 
"date", "2020-12-28", 
"date", "2021-01-04"
```
Despite expected deviation(s) of ISO from Gregorian calendar,  the first and second output are paradoxical. However, this should be raised to [moment](https://github.com/moment/moment), not here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approach I went for was a bit different in the end.
Instead of getting the week number, and then getting the monday of that week number, I simply decided to get the date, get its weekday, eg. Tuesday, and based on that find the monday.

```
  const dayOfTheWeekNumber = toNumber(
    moment(dateKey, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
      .clone()
      .format('e')
  )
  const date = moment(dateKey).subtract(
    dayOfTheWeekNumber === 0 ? 6 : dayOfTheWeekNumber - 1,
    'days'
  )
```

Answer (score 3):

Ciao, I solved your problem by replacing `isoWeek` with `week` like this:

```
const dateKey = "2021-03-29"
const weekNumber = moment(dateKey, 'YYYY-MM-DD').week()
    console.log(weekNumber)
      
      const date = moment(dateKey, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
        .clone()
        .week(weekNumber)
        .day('Monday')
        
        console.log('date', date.format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/1j3azk97/) your code modified.

Anyway, I understand your problem and could be related to the fact that 2020 has 53 weeks and 2021 has 52 weeks.

[image]

So `isoWeek` retruns correctly the 13th week, but `week` retruns 14th (maybe) because it consider every year composed by 52 weeks.

Comment: As was suggested by a comment this should be raised with the moment JS Developers

Comment: I agree, my answer was only a suggest on where could be the porblem of the OP.

Comment: Raising an issue to MomentJs devs is long, and would take a long time. I have to fix this in production, and have no time for it to get fixed, or fix it manually :(

Comment: @Alex and use `week` instead of `isoWeek` coudn't be a good solution?

Comment: Tricky because my entire helper file revolves around standard week (isoWeek is starting Sunday, and I need to start from Monday), and probably requires me to overwrite everything

Comment: Additionally I am getting so many other weird behaviours... That I don't want to create a post about it, like me passing moment('2020-11-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') and as a result getting 2020-11-02 date... literally. WHAT